# Normal Mapping vs Reduce

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert an object into single array with just key and value. I tried two different ways. Though I succeeded in my first attempt but using reduce I am unable to get the result. Please kindly let me know if there is/are better ways of achieving the same. Thank you.

```
  var demoArr = [
            {
                "results": [
                {
                    "listing_id": 10544193
                },
                {
                    "listing_id": 4535435
                }
                ],
                "results1": [
                    {
                        "listing_id": 1054419363
                    },
                    {
                        "listing_id": 432535435
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];
        let aaa = [];
//          demoArr.map(x => {         (before)
            demoArr.forEach(x => {   //(after)
            let ss = Object.values(x);
//          ss.map(y => {              (before) 
            ss.forEach(y => {        //(after)
                y.forEach(k => {
                    aaa.push({"listing_id" : k.listing_id});
                })
               
            });
         });
```

Resulted in the following.

```
[{"listing_id":10544193},{"listing_id":4535435},{"listing_id":1054419363},{"listing_id":432535435}]
```

Is there a better way to achieve the above? Maybe by using reduce? I tried but failed to get the result.

```
         var ds = demoArr.reduce((a,value) => {
            a[value.listing_id] = a[value.listing_id] ? a[value.listing_id] : value
            return a
         },{});
```

Comment: `demoArr.map(x` don't use map if you do nothing with the output.

Comment: Two things: 1. You're [misusing `map`](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/) (not using the array it creates). Just use nested loops. 2. There's no reason for `reduce` here, just use nested loops. :-)

Comment: okay. So i have changed it to ```demoArr.forEach(``` and it resulted in the same output. Thank you for this.

Comment: If the code you have works, and you want the code reviewed, including alternate methods of achieving the same result, you may want to check the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to see if your question is on topic for [codereview.se].

Comment: You're still using `map` incorrectly (`ss.map`). Whenever you use `map`, there should be something using the output of the call.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes I have updated the codes. And yes, now I understand when to use ```map``` now. .Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way use `flatMap()` and `Object.values`, then flatten the result. *Using Object.values as an argument in this fashion is a shorthand for applying the map argument directly into the Object.values method and returning the result*

```js
var demoArr = [{
  "results": [{
      "listing_id": 10544193
    },
    {
      "listing_id": 4535435
    }
  ],
  "results1": [{
      "listing_id": 1054419363
    },
    {
      "listing_id": 432535435
    }
  ]
}];

let output = demoArr.flatMap(Object.values).flat();
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Wow, amazing one. Cheers to JavaScript brains. Anyways, It was still a bouncer for me. Will explore more on flat() and flat.map(). Thank you for this concepts.